# how do you create standalone(just one exe) application with qt?

Tags: qt

how do you create standalone(just one exe) application with qt?

Comment: You write a program which makes use of the Qt toolkit, and then compile it?  Or do you mean a *statically-linked* binary?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  Assuming you mean distributed to any machine without the Qt libraries.  You can, however, easily deploy applications (in Windows) with all needed libraries using the [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) tool.